# How to disable webpack dev server auto reload?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I know most people have the opposite problem but I actually want to disable the auto reload functionality.

This is how I run my server:

```
webpack-dev-server --open --progress
```

This is my dev server config:

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: 'app',
    port: 9005,
    hot: false,
    inline: false
}
```

Versions:

```
"webpack": "1.14.0",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "1.9.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "2.13.2",
"webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.5"
```

With this setup webpack dev server opens the initial page as `localhost:9005/webpack-dev-server/` with auto reload on (`iframe` mode). When I set `inline` to `true` then it opens `localhost:9005` and auto reload is still on (`inline` mode => websockets).

Is there a way to disable auto reload entirely?

Comment: Stop using webpack-dev-server and just run your build scripts as needed?

Comment: I could, but I like my current setup except this one thing.

Comment: Some of these worked, but still kept on compiling the app on the server side every time there was a change; so I finally resorted to setting `serverConfig.watchOptions.ignored = [/.*/];` when required - which stopped the compilation (and reloading) altogether :)

Comment: Hot reload is a disaster for me.  I make some changes, then it looks like the page reloads, but really it hot-loads.  All sorts of error messages about how it can't find this or that, cuz I renamed it.  The debugger's no longer has the right line numbers, so I'm feeling around in the dark.  I have to reload the page by hand.  hot, inline and liveReload are all false.

Answer (score 33):

Working solution for webpack 2.x and 3.x

```
config.devServer = {
    hot: false,
    inline: false,
}
```

Comment: `npm run watch -- --no-inline --no-hot` passes these options to *override* what's in the config (via this alias to `webpack-dev-server --config config.js`)

Answer (score 16):

The webpack client scripts are added by default to your bundle (since webpack 2), but you can disable those by adding `--no-inline` to your CLI command.

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't work. I'm using webpack 1.x,  is that option available only in webpack 2.x? I can't find it  anywhere:  https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html nor there  https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html

Comment: Ah, in iframe mode the client script is always included. There are two ways to fix this;
1) Remove `--open` and manually browse to http://localhost:9005/
2) Add `--lazy`, then it will only recompile when refreshing the page

Comment: Doesn't seem to help with webpack 3.

Comment: Works with Webpack 4

Answer (score 11):

As a workaround I excluded webpack client side scripts from the bundle. This seems to stop auto reload from happening. I did that by redirecting those script to a null loader.

`{test: /webpack-dev-server\\client/, loader: "null-loader"},`

Comment: For posterity: to get this to work in in webpack2 with webpack-dev-server 2.4.5, I had to modify this a bit. I installed https://github.com/webpack-contrib/null-loader and had to exclude by path: 
`{test: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client'), loader: "null-loader"}`

Comment: ^^ This is great. Totally solved the problem. Can you please update your answer to include this extra webpack2 detail?

Answer (score 8):

Here's an update for `webpack-dev-server` 3.x.  Update your `config/webpack/development.js` like so:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

const environment = require('./environment');

environment.config.merge({
  devServer: {
    hot: false,
    inline: false,
    liveReload: false
  }
});

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig();
```

Answer (score 3):

Didn't find an obvious solution either (webpack-dev-server version 1.16.5).

A partial solution seems to be:

```
webpack-dev-server --watch-poll 99999999999
```

This won't rebuild automatically. But it will still reload browser windows after the initial build.