# Why does the browser automatically refresh the project every 30 seconds?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome

I have an angular project that works fine when it's on the server
But on **localHost**, it **automatically** refreshes the browser every 30 seconds

I have not written any code to refresh the page, for example a code like **window.location.reload()**

I tested with browsers like **chrome**, **firefox**, **edge** and they have the same problem

I ran the project with **commandPrompt** and it still had the problem

I also ran **vscode** through **commandPrompt** itself, and it had a problem and the page was refreshing

I don't know if it has anything to do with the browser **cache** or not, but I also deleted it and unfortunately the problem did not go away

And finally, when refreshing, this error is printed on the console and the page is reloaded

[image]

And in the version of my Angular packages, it is like this

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/localize": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^12.2.16",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^3.0.0-preview6.19307.2",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "8.1.0",
    "@circlon/angular-tree-component": "^11.0.4",
    "@formio/angular": "^5.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.1.0",
    "@iplab/ngx-color-picker": "^2.1.1",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^5.0.5",
    "@nebular/eva-icons": "^7.0.0",
    "@nebular/theme": "7.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "10.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^11.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^11.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^17.0.1",
    "@types/codemirror": "0.0.108",
    "ag-grid": "^18.1.2",
    "angular-gauge": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-gauge-chart": "^0.7.2",
    "angular-google-charts": "^2.2.1",
    "angular-gridster2": "^11.1.5",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^12.1.0",
    "angular-responsive-carousel": "^2.1.2",
    "angular2-toaster": "^11.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^1.0.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-zoom": "^1.2.1",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "codemirror": "^5.60.0",
    "core-js": "3.10.1",
    "eva-icons": "^1.1.3",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.5.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fontawesome-4.7": "^4.7.0",
    "formiojs": "^4.14.8",
    "gulp-brotli": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^7.0.0",
    "gulp-gzip": "^1.4.2",
    "gulp-purify-css": "^0.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "html-to-image": "^1.11.11",
    "html-to-pdfmake": "^2.4.16",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "intro.js": "^6.0.0",
    "jalali-moment": "^3.3.11",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jqwidgets-ng": "^12.0.4",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "leaflet": "1.7.1",
    "linq": "^3.2.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "material-jalali-moment-adapter": "^4.0.0",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
    "moment-jalaali": "^0.9.6",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.4",
    "ng-zorro-antd": "^11.4.2",
    "ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
    "ng2-jalali-date-picker": "^2.4.2",
    "ng2-tooltip-directive": "~2.9.22",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-color": "^7.3.3",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-filesize": "^2.0.16",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^6.9.1",
    "ngx-loading": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.3",
    "ngx-permissions": "^8.1.1",
    "ngx-persian": "^1.3.2",
    "ngx-sortablejs": "^11.1.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^12.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.2.1",
    "ngx-ui-switch": "^11.0.1",
    "npm": "^7.9.0",
    "pdfmake": "^0.2.7",
    "primeflex": "^3.2.1",
    "primeicons": "^5.0.0",
    "primeng": "^12.2.3",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "sortablejs": "^1.13.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^10.16.2",
    "swiper": "^6.8.4",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.18",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.18",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.16",
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "^7.0.4",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.19",
    "@types/intro.js": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.184",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.39",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "2.1.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "gulp-zip": "^5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "json-server": "^0.17.1",
    "karma": "^6.3.17",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "rimraf": "3.0.2",
    "stylelint": "13.12.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
```

**I feel that my problem is with the browser itself because I ran another project with localhost:4200 and the problem was the same.**

Comment: Does your browser reload Stack Overflow every 30 seconds?

Comment: Read those error messages. Something ("WDS"?) is performing some kind of "automatic reload". What exactly that means, I can't say. Also you should probably fix that script `import` error.

Comment: No, I did not ask such a question
When I run the project on localhost, my browser automatically refreshes every 30 seconds

Comment: My point is that the problem is not your browser. Your application is doing it somehow.

Comment: I don't know what exactly wds does
Is it related to the network?

Comment: we don't know either, but it's in your project, perhaps as a dependency. If you click on the `index.js` link next to the "live reloading enabled" message in the console you'll see what is printing that message, in which file, and presumably get some context from that that you can look at in your project's files.

Comment: a quick google suggests it might be "webpack dev server", and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41797704/how-to-disable-webpack-dev-server-auto-reload) may be relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your project with this command

```
ng serve --live-reload=false
```